# Simple Producer-consumer implementation in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, concurrency, producer-consumer

I implemented a simple solution to the [Producer–consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem)
 that I'd love for you to take a look at.

The producer simply adds random numbers to a queue and the consumer (from a separate thread) pops numbers off the queue and prints them. I'd specifically like feedback on the concurrency aspects of this implementation. Thanks!

```py
from collections import deque
import random
import threading


TIMES = 100


class SafeQueue:
  def __init__(self, capacity):
    self.capacity = capacity
    self.queue = deque([])
    self.remaining_space = threading.Semaphore(capacity)
    self.fill_count = threading.Semaphore(0)

  def append(self, item):
    self.remaining_space.acquire()
    self.queue.append(item)
    self.fill_count.release()

  def consume(self):
    self.fill_count.acquire()
    item = self.queue.popleft()
    self.remaining_space.release()
    return item


class Producer:
  def __init__(self, queue, times=TIMES):
    self.queue = queue
    self.times = times

  def run(self):
    for _ in range(self.times):
      self.queue.append(random.randint(0, 100))


class Consumer:
  def __init__(self, queue, times=TIMES):
    self.queue = queue
    self.times = times

  def run(self):
    for _ in range(self.times):
      print(self.queue.consume())


def main():
  queue = SafeQueue(10)

  producer = Producer(queue)
  producer_thread = threading.Thread(target=producer.run)
  consumer = Consumer(queue)
  consumer_thread = threading.Thread(target=consumer.run)

  producer_thread.start()
  consumer_thread.start()

  producer_thread.join()
  consumer_thread.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: I dont do much multi-thread processing but from how your code reads it is clean and efficient

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the initial *producer-consumer* scheme is over-complicated and has the following issues:

***Using 2 separate `threading.Semaphore` objects***:
One of them is used for *producer* (`remaining_space`), another - for *consumer* (`fill_count`). 
Though they won't be convenient here (as I'll describe below), but for your future potential cases, a better naming would be `self.producer_counter` and `self.consumer_counter`.
What those 2 semaphors (as internal counters) do is just emulating ***limitation*** of the capacity of a resource (the resource is `deque` in our case)

How it starts and flows:

On running the producer starts appending random items in a loop of `100` iterations:

```
    ...
    for _ in range(self.times):
        self.queue.append(random.randint(0, 100))
```

on each iteration the `producer` thread will acquire `self.remaining_space.acquire()` decrementing the internal counter. When producer's counter is zero (`0`) the `producer` thread will **block** until the `consumer` thread calls `self.remaining_space.release()` thus increasing the producer's counter by `1` and letting the `producer` thread to proceed.
Such a "dragging" of `acquire/release` in multiple places can be just replaced with well-known [**`queue.Queue`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue), which is FIFO queue that already uses `deque` under the hood and already provides the needed *locking* mechanism and *timeout* logic.

> The `queue` module implements multi-producer, multi-consumer queues.
>   It is especially useful in threaded programming when information must
>   be exchanged safely between multiple threads. The `Queue` class in
>   this module implements all the required locking semantics.

...

> ```
> class queue.Queue(maxsize=0)
> ```
>
> Constructor for a FIFO queue. `maxsize` is an integer that sets the upperbound limit on the number of items that can be placed in the
>   queue. Insertion will block once this size has been reached, until
>   queue items are consumed. If `maxsize` is less than or equal to zero,
>   the queue size is infinite.

So `maxsize` already gives us a *limited* *capacity*.

***Namings:***
A better names for a numeric constants in our new scheme would be:

```
MAX_QSIZE = 10  # max queue size
BUF_SIZE = 100  # total number of iterations/items to process
```

***"Tricky" passing of `TIMES` constant:***
It's not good to pass total number of processed items to `Consumer` constructor:

```
class Consumer:
    def __init__(self, queue, times=TIMES):
    ...
```

that allows compromising and specifying *improper* number of items to process.
Consider the following case:

```
TIMES = 100
...
    producer = Producer(queue)
    producer_thread = threading.Thread(target=producer.run)
    consumer = Consumer(queue, times=50)
    consumer_thread = threading.Thread(target=consumer.run)
```

this will point the `consumer` to consume less items than the `queue` contains, eventually having the queue with dangled items.
If you run that case you'll have the pipeline blocked/hanged. 
To avoid that we need to ensure the `consumer` has gotten and processed all items in the queue:

```
class Consumer:
    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while not self.queue.empty():
            item = self.queue.get()
            self.queue.task_done()
            print(item)
```

To enrich the queue communication we can incorporate [`queue.task_done()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.task_done) and [`queue.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.join) (the final version will incorporate them).

*The final concise version:*

```
from queue import Queue
import random
import threading

MAX_QSIZE = 10  # max queue size
BUF_SIZE = 100  # total number of iterations/items to process


class Producer:
    def __init__(self, queue, buf_size=BUF_SIZE):
        self.queue = queue
        self.buf_size = buf_size

    def run(self):
        for _ in range(self.buf_size):
            self.queue.put(random.randint(0, 100))


class Consumer:
    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while not self.queue.empty():
            item = self.queue.get()
            self.queue.task_done()
            print(item)


def main():
    q = Queue(maxsize=MAX_QSIZE)

    producer = Producer(q)
    producer_thread = threading.Thread(target=producer.run)

    consumer = Consumer(q)
    consumer_thread = threading.Thread(target=consumer.run)

    producer_thread.start()
    consumer_thread.start()

    producer_thread.join()
    consumer_thread.join()
    q.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: There's an issue with this code. If producer thread takes a little time to put data into the consumer's queue, there's a chance that consumer will see queue empty and will exit for e.g. if you add this line `time.sleep(1)` before `self.queue.put(random.randint(0, 100))` the program stays at q.join() and never completes. May be we need to synchronize the two threads using an external object e.g. SynchronizationContext